# Javascript for time left in the day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I understand how to work countdown timers and date timers to an extent (to a specified date i.e YYYY-MM-DD) but I'm working on a web development college project where I wish for one of my web pages (JSP file) to have a countdown timer with the number of seconds left in the day from when the web application launches.

The web page will also include an Ajax function where the user can click a button and a random motivational message will appear (this particular piece of code I know, but it's just to give you an idea of why I want this countdown timer).

Comment: Check out this [plugin solution](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

Comment: Create a date `a`. Add one day. Set time to midnight. Create a second date `b`, give `(a - b) / 1000`

Answer (score 6):

Moment.js is a great library for date math. http://momentjs.com/

Using Moment, you could do a one liner like this.

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.write(moment.duration(moment().add(1, 'day').startOf('day').diff(moment())).asSeconds())
</script>
```

or an easier to understand version:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var now = moment(),
    tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day').startOf('day'),
    difference = moment.duration(tomorrow.diff(now))

  document.write(difference.asSeconds())
</script>
```

Comment: This was the most helpful solution, would up vote if I could :)

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

Simply compare the Date object you get from `Date.now()` with the date of tomorrow (which you create from the first date object, adding one day);

```js
var actualTime = new Date(Date.now());

var endOfDay = new Date(actualTime.getFullYear(), actualTime.getMonth(), actualTime.getDate() + 1, 0, 0, 0);


var timeRemaining = endOfDay.getTime() - actualTime.getTime();

document.getElementById('timeRemaining').appendChild(document.createTextNode(timeRemaining / 1000 + " seconds or " + timeRemaining / 1000 / 60 / 60 + " hours"));

document.getElementById('dayProgression').value = 1 - (timeRemaining / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
```

```html
<span id="timeRemaining"></span>

<div>
  <span>How much of the day has passed:</span>
  <progress id="dayProgression" value="0"></progress>
</div>
```

[Example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/g4w29rts/8/)

Comment: Thanks man, I almost got this working but in my application the Bar is just empty in application for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: I added the progress bar just for fun, but this is an [HTML5 element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/progress), which means you need to make sure you use the HTML5 doctype decralation (`<!DOCTYPE HTML>`) instead of regular XHTML/HTML doctypes at the beginning of your document. It also [might not work on some browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=progressmeter) Don't forget to mark the answer as valid once everything is working! If I can help you with anything don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this Javascript code:

```
var year = 2015 , month = 5 , day = 15;
var date = new Date();
var enddate = new Date(year , month , day); 

document.write( date - enddate );
```

You can edit this code for your site.